# Links are not working in details page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, link

The site is made live with the help of **siteworx panel**. The Links & Buttons in the details page alone are not working. I uploaded the code to server via **Bitbucket** using **git**. The same code in my local machine is working very fine. But the links & buttons are not working only in the live site.

Kindly suggest me solutions regarding what can be the issue?
Which is stopping my links & buttons in the live site from working fine?

> I have added Zopim chat only in the live site. But even when I
>   disabled that extension the links and buttons are not working.

Comment: is both site in `localhost` and in `live site` is both are exactly same ?

Comment: yes. Its same code.

Comment: don't you have any other demo sites in server ? also before you push the code through `git`, is those buttons were working? try to go for older commit or remove those codes and check, is there any error in browser console, is it possible for you to check by disabling other 3-rd party modules... check log files under var folder once.....

Comment: Yes I disabled the third party module and tried. Then also the links are not working.